# Is there a concurrent sorted dictionary or something similar?

Tags: c#, concurrency, sorteddictionary

For a project we've been working on we used a concurrent dictionary, which was fine until a new specification came up which required the dictionary to be sorted (it should remain in the order it was added, kind of like a FIFO).

This is currently what we do, we take an x amount (5 in this case) of items out of the dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<PriorityOfMessage, ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, PriorityMessage>> mQueuedMessages = new Dictionary<PriorityOfMessage, ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, PriorityMessage>>();


var messages = new List<KeyValuePair<Guid, PriorityMessage>>();
messages.AddRange(mQueuedMessages[priority].Take(5));
```

then we do some things with it and eventually if everything succeeds we removed them.

```
mQueuedMessages[priority].TryRemove(messageOfPriority.Key);
```

However if things fail we won't remove them and try later. So unfortunatly there is no concurrent sorted dictionary, but are there ways to ensure the messages stay in the order they are added?

It is very important we can take multiple objects from the list/dictionary without removing them (or we need to be able to add them to the front later).

Comment: What about `ConcurrentQueue<T>`?

Comment: Maybe just use a lock? What kinds of concurrency requirements do you have? It's hard to over-stress a lock if the critical region is small.

Comment: @Rahul I need to be able to see more than just the first, in a queue you can only see the first object in the queue without removing it, if you remove something you can't put it back.

Comment: @usr locks slow it down to much unfortunately, my colleague has already tried using locks and lists and he deemed it too slow.

Comment: How often will you take per second?

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat The `ConcurrentQueue<T>` class implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can call `.ToList()` and you'll get all the items in the queue without actually removing them from the queue. If you call `TryDequeue(out item)` you **will** get one of the items you just retrieved when you called `.ToList()`.

Comment: @Maarten but i can imagine doing ToList() for a list of tens of thousands of items might be very slow. wouldn't it? And we need more than 1 item to work with, taking a single one every time would make it quite slow.

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat Then do `queue.Take(5).ToList()` or whatever suits your purpose. But 'tens of thousands' of in-memory-objects are still iterated over pretty quick.

Comment: @Maarten but then we cannot put them back in case we cannot handle x of those 5. Take does actually take them out of the queue right?

Comment: Did you overlook my question? Here it is again: How often will you take per second? This is important to know for performance considerations.

Comment: @usr sorry i did read it, but i'm having a debate with my coworker, he says it could be a thousand times a second, maybe even more. though I now believe a lock would hardly be needed (don't get me wrong we would surely need it, but i believe it will only be called in special cases so not that many).

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes we might need to implement a normal list with a lock, and work around the need for a dictionary. though unfortunately List.Find(x => x.Identifier == GUID); is so much slower than using the GUID as a key in the dictionary... We are going to make our speed tests tomorrow and see what the difference will be for using locks instead of concurrent, and list.find instead of dictionary.key. but with a list of tens of thousands of items i can already tell it's going to be slow (the .Find, lock might actually not be that slow).

Comment: What is the usecase for List.Find(x => x.Identifier == GUID); find if the item is in the queue or something else,  why cant the object also be in a dict and you add/remove it from both?

Comment: And Take does NOT remove items from a queue, non of the IEnumerable usages of a queue will alter its contents

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How often will you take per second?

.

> it could be a thousand times a second

1000 lock operations per second are absolutely nothing. This will consume almost no time at all.

> my colleague has already tried using locks and lists and he deemed it too slow

In all likelihood this means that the locked region was too big. My guess is it went something like that:

```
lock (...) {
 var item = TakeFromQueue();
 Process(item);
 DeleteFromQueue(item);
}
```

This does not work because `Process` is too slow. It must be:

```
lock (...)
 var item = TakeFromQueue();

 Process(item);

lock (...)
 DeleteFromQueue(item);
```

You will not have any perf problems with that at all.

You can now pick any data structure that you like. You are no longer bound by the capabilities of the built-in concurrent data structures. Besides picking a data structure that you like you also can perform any operation on it that you like such as taking multiple items atomically.

I have not fully understood your needs but it sounds like `SortedList` might go in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You could also go for another solution (haven't tested it performance-wise):

```
public class ConcurrentIndexableQueue<T> {
    private long tailIndex;
    private long headIndex;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<long, T> dictionary;

    public ConcurrentIndexableQueue() {
        tailIndex = -1;
        headIndex = 0;
        dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<long, T>();
    }

    public long Count { get { return tailIndex - headIndex + 1; } }

    public bool IsEmpty { get { return Count == 0; } }

    public void Enqueue(T item) {
        var enqueuePosition = Interlocked.Increment(ref tailIndex);
        dictionary.AddOrUpdate(enqueuePosition, k => item, (k, v) => item);
    }

    public T Peek(long index) {
        T item;

        return dictionary.TryGetValue(index, out item) ? 
            item : 
            default(T);
    }

    public long TryDequeue(out T item) {
        if (headIndex > tailIndex) {
            item = default(T);
            return -1;
        }

        var dequeuePosition = Interlocked.Increment(ref headIndex) - 1;

        dictionary.TryRemove(dequeuePosition, out item);

        return dequeuePosition;
    }

    public List<T> GetSnapshot() {
        List<T> snapshot = new List<T>();
        long snapshotTail = tailIndex;
        long snapshotHead = headIndex;

        for (long i = snapshotHead; i < snapshotTail; i++) {
            T item;

            if (TryDequeue(out item) >= 0) {
                snapshot.Add(item);
            }
        }

        return snapshot;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this implementation will not pass this test `Parallel.For(0, 1000, i => queue.Enqueue(queue.Count))`. Expected : `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`. Actual: `0,0,0,3,4,5,6,7,7,7`. Either `Count` should be locked or `Enqueue` should schedule threads to complete.

Comment: @Anonymous, no concurrent collection is guaranteed to provide the results you are expecting (though they won't crash or otherwise misbehave where non-concurrent collections might). Using two atomic operations together does not make the combined operation atomic.